# Java beginner help, cannot resolve a variable

Tags: java, variables, scope

I'm trying to make sure that the variable num is only 5 digits long, but my while and return statements say that num cannot be resolved to a variable. What can be done?

```
 import java.util.*;
    public class program1
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int num;
    num = getnum();
    System.out.print(num);
  }
  public static int getnum()
  {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    do
    {
    System.out.println("Enter a number that has only five digits ");
    int num = console.nextInt(); 
    }
    while (num < 10000 || num > 99999);
    return num;
  }
}
```

Comment: you declared `num` as local varible, you can't access it outside scope.

Comment: better review the "scope" concept :) Or learn compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `num` outside of the loop.

```
int num;
do
{
    System.out.println("Enter a number that has only five digits ");
    num = console.nextInt(); 
} while (num < 10000 || num > 99999);
```

This is due to variable scoping. It's a bit annoying, but a variable declared in the `do` portion of a do-while isn't available in the `while` portion.

Comment: I actually already tried that and it says its a local duplicate variable.

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part; the `num =` part should _not_ start with `int`.

Comment: Because whenever you write `int num`, you're declaring a new variable named `num`. You can't do it twice within a given scope (including nested scopes), because you can't have two variables with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a variable belongs to the scope that it was declared in. A variable declaration looks like:

```
<type> <variable name>;
```

Or, in your case `int num`. You declare `num` in the `do...while()` loop, so it belongs to the `do...while()` loop. If you want to use `num` in the method `getnum` then it's best to declare it near the start of the method:

```
public static int getnum() 
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a number that has only five digits ");
        num = console.nextInt(); 
    }
    while (num < 10000 || num > 99999);
    return num;
}
```

This allows you to access `num` anywhere inside of the method, so you can assing it and then return it when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing is to make sure you define "num" *outside* of your "do" loop:

```
import java.util.*;

  public class program1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int num = getnum();
      System.out.print(num);
    }

    public static int getnum() {
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      int num;
      do {
        System.out.println("Enter a number that has only five digits ");
        num = console.nextInt(); 
      } while (num < 10000 || num > 99999);
      return num;
   }
}
```